# How do I create a card like this in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to create a card like this in Android Studio, but I'm still new to Frontend Development. Do you have any suggestions for Layouts I could use to realize this?
[image]

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use constraint layout with CardView.
I started it for you. You can continue it. There is the simpliest way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#7AFFFFFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Expenses"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightDecorView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/title"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/title"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/durationTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Duration"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/titleDivider"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/titleDivider"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleDivider" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/durationView"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_car_placeholder"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/durationTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/durationTitle" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/durationDiff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_car_placeholder"
                android:text="+ 10 min"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/durationView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/durationTitle" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/durationTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_car_placeholder"
                android:text="= 2h 15 km"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/durationDiff"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/durationDiff" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/rightDecorView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_car_placeholder"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

To simplify layout, you can separate a repeating view to another custom view. And just reuse it in your code.

Look how to do it here https://blogs.oregonstate.edu/workla/2021/11/04/creating-a-custom-view-in-android/

Comment: This looks great, thank you so much :)! I think I will be able to do the rest with the start you've provided me with. This was a great help!